# 3-digit integer number program won't execute

Tags: c

Yes, this is a basic C coding homework problem. No, I am not just looking for someone to do it for me. Considering that this is my first programming class, I'm not surprised that I can't get it to work, and I'm certain there is plenty wrong with it. I just want some help pointing out the problems in my code and the things that are missing so that I can fix them on my own.

**Homework Question:**

> Write a program to read ONLY one integer number (your input must be
>   one    3 digit number from 100 to 999), and to think of a number as
>   being ABC   (where A, B, and C are the 3 digits of a number). Now,
>   form  the  number   to become ABC, BCA, and CAB, then find out the
>   remainder of  these three   numbers when they are divided by 11.
>   Assume remainders would  respectively   be X, Y, and Z  and  add  them
>   up  as  X+Y, Y+Z, and  Z+X. Now if any  of   these summations is odd
>   number, increase it by 11 if the summation plus 11   is less than 20,
>   otherwise  decrease the  summation  by 11 (this summation   operation
>   must  be positive  number but  less than 20). Finally, divide   each
>   of the sums in half. Now, print out all the resulting digits.

**My Code:**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Declare all variables
    int OrigNumber;
    int x, y, z;
    int number;
    number = x, y, z;
    int sum;
    //
    printf("Input a three digit number");
    //
    int c;
    c = OrigNumber %10;
    //
    int b;
    b=((OrigNumber - c) % 100)/10;
    //
    int a;
    a = (OrigNumber - (b + c))/100;
    //
    int abc, bca, cab;
    abc = (a*100) + (10*b) + c;
    bca = (10*b) + c + (a*100);
    cab = c + (a*100) + (10*b);
    //
    if((number % 2) == 1)
        {
            if(number + 11 < 20)
                number += 11;
            else if((100 - 11 > 0) && (100 - 11 < 20))
                number -= 11;
        }
    //
    x = abc/11;
    y = bca/11;
    z = cab/11;
    //
    sum = (x + y),
          (y + z),
          (z + x);
}
```

Comment: The **big trick** is to start with something small and simple that works, then build up step by step. What do you want first? A program that accepts a number from the user? A program that can break 279 into 2, 7 and 9? A program that can do the +/-11 thing?

Comment: Given the question, I think it would be best to sort out that can allow the input of the three digit number, as that is where the program crashes.

Comment: All right, if you look up "input" in your text (or google "C input") you'll find that `scanf` is good for that, like so: `scanf("%d", &OrigNumber);`

Comment: Two things: first is there is no statement that would cause any input to be captured; the second is that the line “`number = x, y, z;`” probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You ask for a number, but never read anything. Your `a`, `b`, and `c` have unclear meanings. For 123, are they 100, 20, and 3; or 1, 2, and 3? Compile the program with mild optimization and all typical warnings (for GCC, `-O -Wall`), and either *understand* and fix each warning or make *sure* you are right and the compiler confused (that happens much, much more rarely than you'd think).

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you need to read the input. Start with a prompt that includes a carriage return:

```
printf("Input a three digit number: \n");
```

Since it's a three digit number, you could add the following line to read the input:

```
scanf("%3d", &OrigNumber);
```

The next bit of code works quite well until you get to your `if (number % 2)` which is meaningless since you didn't really define `number` - well, you did, but the line

```
number = x, y, z;
```

does NOT do what you think it does.  If you add

```
printf("So far I have abc=%d, bca=%d, cab=%d\n", abc, bca, cab);
```

after you first read in the number and computed those three, you will see you are well on your way.

Note that

```
number = x, y, z;
```

Uses a thing called the "comma operator". All the things (a,b,c) are "evaluated" but their values are not returned. At any rate, where you have that line, you didn't yet assign a value to x,y and z.

Is that enough to get your started?

**update** now that you have had a few hours to mull this over, here are a few more pointers.

Your computation of `abc, cab, bca` makes no sense. I will show you just one of them:

```
cab = c*100 + a*10 + b;
```

Next you need to compute each of x, y and z.  Again, here is one of the three:

```
y = bca%11;
```

Now you have to make the sums - I call them `xy`, `yz`, and `zx`. Just one of them:

```
zx = z + x;
```

Next, to deal with the instruction: "Now if any of these summations is odd number, increase it by 11 if the summation plus 11 is less than 20, otherwise decrease the summation by 11:

```
if(xy % 2 == 1) {
  if(xy + 11 < 20) xy += 11; else xy -= 11;
}
```

use similar code for all three sums. Then "divide by 2":

```
xy /= 2;
```

repeat as needed.

Finally, print out the result:

```
printf("xy: %d, yz: %d, zx: %d\n", xy, yz, zx);
```

The amazing thing is that if you did this right, you get the original numbers back...

You could make the code more compact by using an array of values and looping through it - rather than repeating the code snippets I wrote above with different variables. But I suspect that is well outside the scope of what you are expected to know at this point.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Well, it at least got me to the point of being able to input the 3-digit number and enter it.

Comment: @user3399871 - I have updated my answer. Lots more (hopefully useful) information now. Still leaving you to figure out some of it for yourself. Whatever you do - STOP using the comma operator. Make sure variables have a value assigned before you use them. C is not like a "symbolic math" language.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //Declare all variables
    int OrigNumber;
    int a, b, c;
    int abc, bca, cab;
    int x, y, z;
    int xplusy , yplusz, xplusz;

    printf(" A program to read ONLY one integer number.\n Input must be one 3 digit number from 100 to 999 : ");    
    scanf("%d", &OrigNumber);   // Get input from console

    if(OrigNumber > 999 || OrigNumber < 100) {
        printf("Invalid number. Quiting program. This is error handling. Important while learning programming.");   
    return 0;
    }

    c = OrigNumber %10; // digit at unit's place

    b=((OrigNumber) % 100)/10; //digit at the ten's place

    a = (OrigNumber)/100; //digit at the 100's place. Note: 734/100 = 7. NOT 7.34.

    printf("\n Three numbers say A,B, C : %d, %d , %d ", a, b, c);  

    abc = a*100 + 10*b + c;
    bca = 100*b + 10*c + a;
    cab = c*100 + a*10 + b;

    printf("\n Three numbers say ABC, BCA, CAB : %d, %d , %d ", abc, bca, cab);

    x = abc % 11;   // Reminder when divided by 11.
    y = bca % 11;
    z = cab % 11;

    printf("\n Three numbers say X, Y, Z : %d, %d , %d ", x, y, z);

    xplusy = x + y; // Adding reminders two at a time.
    yplusz = y + z;
    xplusz = x + z;

    printf("\n Three numbers  X+Y, Y+Z, X+Z : %d, %d , %d ", xplusy, yplusz, xplusz);

    if((xplusy % 2) == 1) {
        if(xplusy + 11 < 20)
            xplusy += 11;
        else
        xplusy -= 11;
    }

    if((yplusz % 2) == 1) {
        if(yplusz + 11 < 20)
            yplusz += 11;
        else
            yplusz -= 11;
    }

    if((xplusz % 2) == 1) {
        if(xplusz + 11 < 20)
            xplusz += 11;
        else
            xplusz -= 11;
    }

    xplusy /= 2; // Finally, divide each of the sum in half.
    yplusz /= 2;
    xplusz /= 2;

    printf("\n Now print out all the resulting digits :  %d, %d , %d \n", xplusy, yplusz, xplusz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah - this should help a lot. One comment though - you are not really leaving the OP much opportunity to "learn from doing"...

Comment: This post is to acknowledge how important error handling is and to make aware the OP that the key to programming is 'divide and conquer'. Take one challenge at a time. Use the result to proceed to next challenge. Every single program has essentially some inputs and an output.

Answer (score 0):

```
int abc, bca, cab;
abc = (a*100) + (10*b) + c;
bca = (10*b) + c + (a*100);
cab = c + (a*100) + (10*b);
```

I suggest printing out the numbers at this point in the code.

```
printf( "%d %d %d", abc, bca, cab );
```

I think you'll see one of the problems you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, a, b, c, abc, bca, cab, x, y, z, p, q, r;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    c=n%10;
    b=(n/10)%10;
    a=n/100;
    abc=a*100+b*10+c;
    bca=b*100+c*10+a;
    cab=c*100+a*10+b;
    x=abc%11;
    y=bca%11;
    z=cab%11;
    p=x+y;
    q=y+z;
    r=z+x;
    return 0;
}
```

> Now if any of these summations is odd number, increase it by 11 if the
>   summation plus 11 is less than 20, otherwise decrease the summation by
>   11 (this summation operation must be positive number but less than
>   20). Finally, divide each of the sums in half. Now, print out all the
>   resulting digits.

i didnt get the final part, can you explain it more clearly?